# Ubuntu-Windows : Unhide hidden drive

Tags: windows-7

I am installing two OS : Ubuntu and Windows7 in my system. I have 3 drives,
C: windows7 is installed.
D: Ubuntu is installed.
E: My personal files are stored.

**Problem:**

When I use Windows7, I could not see D: drive. Is that the security feature of Linux? 
How can I unhidden the drive in Win7?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and Windows have different file system. The partition type are different and they have different partition table strategies.

May be you can search some of the applications which can allow you to use EXT type extensions in Windows OS.

Comment: Ubuntu supports many different file systems, including Windows-type filesystems like FAT32. However, the default file system is EXT3 or EXT4 (depending on distribution), neither of which can be read by Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response, mates. I am searching solution. Let's see.